# Mac Os X how to clean system from my files

Tags: macos

On my job, I received mac. So at some point of time, I would need to give it back. How to clean Mac from all my files?
As far as I understand I have to delete my files in ~/ directory. Also I think it would be nice to delete my Applications.
But what else? Some hidden caches/backup folders etc?

Comment: Easiest way is simply reinstall the Mac OS X, but usually that will be done by your workplace IT department. For yourself, just grab all your personal files off the Mac, and delete them. If it is work-related files, you may want to leave them in the Mac.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I might don't know all the places where my files can be. For instance, ~/.Trash folder. But there might be some other folders above my user directory, which I simply don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get a clean system is to re-install OS X. But if you're not able to do so, I would recommend that you remove your own user account. 
Also check these folders for cleaning (ie don't just delete, but check them for stuff you already removed from the system) :

```
/Library/Applications
/Library/Application Support
/Library/Preferences
/Library/PreferencesPanes
/Library/Screen Savers
/Library/Widgets
/Users/<your username>
```

You can access these folders with CMD + SHIFT + G in Finder.